# Exportar resultado de query a excel

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite

tengo un problema al exportar el resultado de una consulta a excel, estoy usando laravel 10 y maatwebsite 3.1 para la exportación, el problema es que la data la está poniendo en una sola fila evitando que se pueda leer de manera correcta, la exportación se ve asi
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero deberia verse asi, los datos salen solo de una tabla, esta es mi funcion

```
public function collection(): Collection
{
    // Campos para columnas
    $columns = $this->serviceService->getField();
    $dataColumns = [];
    foreach ($columns as $column) {
        $dataColumns[] = array_values($column);
    }
    // Transponer los datos utilizando array_map y null
    $transposeColumns = array_map(null, ...$dataColumns);

    // Valores
    $values = $this->serviceService->getKardex($this->selectedMonth);
    $dataValues = [];
    foreach ($values as $value) {
        $dataValues[] = array_values($value->toArray());
    }
    // Transponer los datos utilizando array_map y null
    $transposeValues = array_map(null, ...$dataValues);

    // Crear una colección a partir de los datos transpuestos
    $columnsCollection = new Collection($transposeColumns);
    $valuesCollection = new Collection($transposeValues);

    // Dividir los valores en conjuntos de tamaño igual al número de columnas
    $chunks = array_chunk($dataValues, count($dataColumns));

    // Crear una colección de filas combinando columnas y valores
    $combinedCollection = new Collection();
    foreach ($chunks as $chunk) {
        foreach ($chunk as $valueRow) {
            $combinedRow = array_merge($transposeColumns, $valueRow);
            $combinedCollection->push($combinedRow);
        }
    }

    return $combinedCollection; 
}
```

[![
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKfik.png)][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKfik.png)

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo hacer un export general. En mi caso uso `MasterExport`:

```
namespace App\Exports;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromArray;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;

class MasterExport implements FromArray, WithHeadings
{
    /**
    * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
    */
    protected $headings;
    protected $data;

    function __construct(array $headings,array $data) {
        $this->headings = $headings;
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function headings(): array
    {
        return $this->headings;
    }

    public function array(): array
    {
        return $this->data;
    }
}
```

Después crea el arreglo de títulos y de datos, y lo permites descargar así:

```
$headings = Array('Titulo 1','Titulo 2');
$data[] = Array('Dato A2','Dato B2');
$data[] = Array('Dato A3','Dato B3');

return Excel::download(new MasterExport(compact('headings'),compact('data')), "Tu archivo.xlsx");
```